# Accessing props in .then (React/redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, redux-thunk

My project is using react, redux, and redux-thunk.

I want to wait for my function to end before launching a function that clear my page. Unofortunately i have a problem accessing my function in .then

Here was my previous code without promise and then :

```
this.props.dispatch(ScheduleAction(..))
this.props.deleteTab()
```

the problem was that sometime deleteTab() is called before sending the info to my server so not very good.

then i did :

```
Promise.resolve(this.props.dispatch(ScheduleAction(..)))
  .then(function(response) {
         this.props.deleteTab();
         console.log("TabDeleted !!!");
         return response
   })
```

The problem now is that i can't access `this.props.deleteTab();`

And i have this as error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

If anyone have an idea on how to fix that by accessing props in .then, thanks in advance !!

Comment: have you tried of defining `this.props` outside of your `promise`? Or you can also pass `this.props` as parameter in your `.then()` function parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. You don't have access to this inside then. If you use arrow methods as below, you should be able to access it.

```
Promise.resolve(this.props.dispatch(ScheduleAction(..)))
  .then((response)=> {
         this.props.deleteTab();
         console.log("TabDeleted !!!");
         return response
   })
```

Comment: effectively the arrow declarative function in EcmaScript 6 : http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies

allow you to get this, thanks totally forget about that !

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that you lost the context of `this` keyword, which means `this` now is undefined.

Since you can access `this.props` outside the promise, what you want is to `bind` `this` inside your `promise` function by doing smth like this

```
Promise.resolve(this.props.dispatch(ScheduleAction(..)))
  .bind(this)
  .then(function(response) {
         this.props.deleteTab();
         console.log("TabDeleted !!!");
         return response
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this method work for you

```
const $this = this;
const { dispatch } = this.props;

Promise.resolve(dispatch(ScheduleAction(..)))
.then(function(response) {
  $this.deleteTab();
  console.log("TabDeleted !!!");
  return response;
})
```